# Which takes precedence: Rails type casting or validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I am very curious about what this expected behavior is for Rails 4.2 and I have not been able to find an answer to my question.

I'm adding validation to a model on all the time attributes. I want them to ONLY accept integers, not numerical strings. The data type in my schema for this attribute is an integer. I have my validation like so:

```
RANGE = 0..59
validates :start_minute,   inclusion: { in: RANGE }, numericality: true
```

I've tried these other validations as well. I get the same result.

```
validates_numericality_of :start_minute, inclusion: { 0..59, only_integer: true }

validates :start_minute, inclusion: { in: 0..59 }, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

When I pass my params to my controller from the request spec, `start_minute` is `"12"`. BUT when I look at the created object, the `start_minute`  is `12`.

According to [this article by ThoughtBot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-rails-works-type-casting):

*"This is because Active Record automatically type casts all input so that it matches the database schema. Depending on the type, this may be incredibly simple, or extremely complex."*

Shouldn't the object not be able to be created? Is the typecasting taking precedence of my validation? Or is there something wrong with my validation? I appreciate any insight to this as I haven't been able to determine what is happening here. I've also created a model spec for this and I'm still able to create a new object with numerical strings.

Thank you for any insight you can give on this. I am still learning the magic of Rails under the hood.

Comment: Forms in HTML are not typed so user input will be strings regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) it says,

> If you set :only_integer to true, then it will use the
>
> /\A[+-]?\d+\z/

What it(only_integer validator) does is that **it validates that the format of value matches the regex above** and a string value that contains only numbers like '12' is a match(returns a truthy value which is 0 and passes the validation).

```
2.3.1 :001 > '12' =~ /\A[+-]?\d+\z/
 => 0
```